# package com.oracle.svm.core doesn't exist

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I was something related to graal and so I need to use `com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.*` in my code.
My compiler is complaining `package com.oracle.svm.core.annotate does not exist`

I was using graalvm-java11 sdk, the compiling log is also showing that it's using the right sdk

```
Compiling with toolchain '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/Contents/Home'.
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
```

more about my env:

```
➜  map-java-service git:(master) ✗echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/Contents/Home
➜  map-java-service git:(master) ✗ which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

I thought this would be by default include, is there anything else I need to configure before I can use `com.oracle.svm.core`?

**Added:**
I've installed native-image

```
➜  ~ native-image --version
GraalVM 21.1.0 Java 11 CE (Java Version 11.0.11+8-jvmci-21.1-b05)
```

Comment: did you installed native-image?
gu install native-image

Comment: @MunishChouhan yes it's installed 
'''
➜  ~ native-image --version
GraalVM 21.1.0 Java 11 CE (Java Version 11.0.11+8-jvmci-21.1-b05)
'''

Comment: you can check this GitHub repo for more info on native-image build tools: https://github.com/graalvm/native-build-tools